# Show cursor pointing coordinates along with cursor

Tags: vb.net

I want to show the cursor pointing coordinates as an ordered pair`(x,y)` along with the cursor whenever any point in the form is clicked.

Is it possible to do this?

- I am using `vb.net` windows application.
- I tried to do this but all result in error

Comment: Can you show us the code that you used that resulted in an error?  It will be easier to give you help if we know what you have already attempted.

Comment: thanks to all for your response i got the answer from sample as posted below. thanks a lot.; that was actually am looking for

Comment: ammuviswas If the answer posted below is what you where looking for please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use form's `mouse click` event for this. let `label1` is a label control in your form named `frmcursor` then you can code like this :

```
Private Sub frmcursor_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
    Label1.Left = e.X ' x coordinate of cursor point 
    Label1.Top = e.Y  ' y coordinate of the cursor point
    Label1.Text = "(" & e.X.ToString & "," & e.Y.ToString & ")" 'will display the coordinates as ordered pair
End Sub
```

**Updates :**

if you want to show it when ever cursor focusing the form then your code will be like :

```
Private Sub frmcursor_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    Label1.Left = e.X
    Label1.Top = e.Y
    Label1.Text = "(" & e.X.ToString & "," & e.Y.ToString & ")"
End Sub
```